# Bamboo REST API access manually overridden variables

Tags: rest, bamboo

No luck over at the Atlassian Q/A board.

I'm trying to access bamboo project build version info via the REST API with the endpoint format:

```
http://bambooprod01.mysite.com:8085/rest/api/latest/plan/PROD-myproject?expand=variableContext
```

which returns an outdated version.  When I view the information on bamboo I see the correct version of the build under the meta data tab, and above the info fields it states

```
"The following parameters have been manually overridden."
```

**QUESTION: Is there a way to access the overridden variable info via a REST endpoint and if so what would the path be?**

Answer (score 2):

Got a response via Atlassian.

[Atlassian Post](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/43733945/rest-api-access-manually-overridden-variables)

> Unfortunately, this response has not being implemented and there is an
>   improvement request filed for that  BAM-13511 - Expose the build
>   variables via the REST API OPEN.